# Check if SVG exists in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svg

I have the following code as a helper that I want to use to check if an image exists and if so then return it's raw SVG data:

```
def svg(name: 'default')
  file = asset_path('images/' + name + '.svg')
  if( File.file?(file) )
    file = File.open(file, 'rb')
    contents = file.read
    file.close
    contents.html_safe
  end
end
```

However the file always comes back false... (the svg exists!)

Is the way I'm getting the file incorrect?

Comment: I believe asset path is the relative public URL to the file. You might be better off by asking for `Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'images', "#{name}.svg")`